# Setting database owner to a role does not allow users to create table

Tags: hive, hiveql, sql-grant

In Apache Hive, I set the owner of a database to a role.

Users have been assigned this role.

The users cannot create table in this database.

Error is:

> Principal (name=xx, type=USER) does not have following privileges for
>   operation CREATETABLE on object type database

How can I allow more that one user to have create table (as well as all other privileges) on a database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mistake was made during the definition of the owner.

The command should have been:

```
alter database mydb set owner role myrole
```

Instead of

```
alter database mydb set owner user myrole
```